# Bootstrap 3: choosing between pills, tabs and button-group

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Let's say I have a page with multiple items, and I would like to add an ability to filter by some predifined conditions. Like this: All | Condition 1 | Condition 2

Basically, "All" disables all filters and "Condition 1" and "Condition 2" filter the items by one of two different conditions.

How do I choose between pills, tabs and button-group option for navigating these three options? Is there any general rule or should I simply choose one that looks prettier?

Comment: generally speaking, i would expect some kind of checkboxes or optionboxes for that...

Answer (score 1):

Because (as I understood) the result will stay in the same panel I would choose to have a button-group with a different style for the one that is selected, because the tabs should be used if you change (show/hide) the content panel...

But I think the choice should be the result of an ergonomical analyses than really choosing between two elements...